# Python Crash Course Getting an error when run says group object has no attribute sprite

Tags: python

The code runs and it works then pops up error at line at the end. ai.run_game() is where it occurs. i can see the ship and aliens move then it pops up the error. I dont know what i am doing wrong I followed the book exactly. Does anybody have any ideas on what I should do to fix this. I am doing this in Visual Studios. Here is the code:
alien_invasion.py

```
import sys

import pygame
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
from bullet import Bullet
from alien import Alien

class AlienInvasion:
    """Overall class to manage game assets and behavior."""
    def __init__(self):
        """Intitialize the game and create new resources."""
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.settings.screen_width,   self.settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")
    self.ship = Ship(self)
    self.bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
    self.aliens = pygame.sprite.Group()
    self._create_fleet()
    
def run_game(self):
    """Start the main loop for the game."""
    while True:
        self._check_events()
        self.ship.update()
        self._update_bullets()
        self._update_aliens()
        self._update_screen()
        # Watch for a keyboard and mouse events.
def _check_events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                self._check_keydown_events(event)
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                self._check_keyup_events(event)
def _check_keydown_events(self, event):
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        #move ship to the right
            self.ship.moving_right = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.ship.moving_left = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            self._fire_bullet()
def _check_keyup_events(self, event):
    """Respond to key releases"""
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        self.ship.moving_right = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        self.ship.moving_left = False 
def _fire_bullet(self):
    """Create a new bullet and add it to the bullet group"""
    if len(self.bullets) < self.settings.bullets_allowed:
        new_bullet = Bullet(self)
        self.bullets.add(new_bullet)
def _update_bullets(self):
    """Update position of bullets and get rid of old bullets"""
    #Update bullet positions
    self.bullets.update()
    #Get rid of old bullets
    for bullet in self.bullets.copy():
            if bullet.rect.bottom <= 0:
                self.bullets.remove(bullet)
def _update_aliens(self):
    """update the positions of all aliens in the fleet"""
    #check if alien is at an edge and then update positions.
    self._check_fleet_edges()
    self.aliens.update()
def _create_fleet(self):
    """Create a fleet of aliens."""
    #make an alien and find the number of aliens in a row.
    #spacing between one alien is equal to one alien width
    alien = Alien(self)
    alien_width, alien_height = alien.rect.size
    available_space_x = self.settings.screen_width - (2 * alien_width)
    number_aliens_x = available_space_x // (2 * alien_width)
    #Determine the number of rows of aliens that fit on screen
    ship_height = self.ship.rect.height
    available_space_y = (self.settings.screen_height  - (3 * alien_height) - ship_height)
    number_rows = available_space_y // (2 * alien_height)
    #create first row of aliens
    for row_number in range(number_rows):
        for alien_number in range(number_aliens_x):
            self._create_alien(alien_number, row_number)
def _create_alien(self, alien_number, row_number):
        #Create alien place in row
        alien = Alien(self)
        alien_width, alien_height = alien.rect.size
        alien.x = alien_width + 2 * alien_width * alien_number
        alien.rect.x = alien.x
        alien.rect.y = alien.rect.height + 2 * alien.rect.height * row_number
        self.aliens.add(alien)
def _check_fleet_edges(self):
    """Respond appropriately if any aliens have reached an edge."""
    for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
        if alien.check_edges():
            self._change_fleet_direction()
            break
def _change_fleet_direction(self):
    """Drop the entire fleet and change direction"""
    for alien in self.aliens.sprite():
        alien.rect.y += self.settings.fleet_drop_speed
    self.settings.fleet_direction *= -1
def _update_screen(self):
    """Update images on screen and flip to the new screen."""
    self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
    self.ship.blitme()
    for bullet in self.bullets.sprites():
        bullet.draw_bullet()
    self.aliens.draw(self.screen)
    #Make the most recently drawn screen visible
    pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
#Make a game instance, and run the game
ai = AlienInvasion()
ai.run_game()
```

settings.py

```
class Settings:
    """A class to store all the settings for Alien Invasion"""
    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game's settings."""
        #Screen settings
        self.screen_width = 800
        self.screen_height = 600
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
        #ship settings
        self.ship_speed = 1.5
        #bullet settings
        self.bullet_speed = 1.0
        self.bullet_width = 3
        self.bullet_height = 15
        self.bullet_color = (60, 60, 60)
        self.bullets_allowed = 3
        #alien settings
        self.alien_speed = 1.0
        self.fleet_drop_speed = 10
        #Fleet direction of 1 represents right, -1 left.
        self.fleet_direction = 1
```

bullet.py

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Bullet(Sprite):
    """A class to manage bullets fired from the ship."""
     def __init__(self, ai_game):
        """Create a bullet object at the ships current position"""
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.settings = ai_game.settings
        self.color = self.settings.bullet_color

        #Create a bullet rect at (0,0) and then set correct position
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, self.settings.bullet_width, self.settings.bullet_height)
        self.rect.midtop = ai_game.ship.rect.midtop

        #Store the bullets position as a decimal value
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)

    def update(self):
        """Move the bullet up the screen"""
        #Update the decimal position of the bullet.
        self.y -= self.settings.bullet_speed
        #Update rect position.
        self.rect.y = self.y
    def draw_bullet(self):
        """Draw the bullet to the screen"""
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)
```

alien.py

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Alien(Sprite):
    """A class to represent a single alien in the fleet."""
    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        """Initialize the alien and set its starting position."""
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.settings = ai_game.settings

        #Load the alien image and set is rect attribute.
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Images/alien.bmp")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        #Starte each new alien near the top left of the screen
        self.rect.x = self.rect.width
        self.rect.y = self.rect.height

        #Store the aliens exact horizontal position
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
    def check_edges(self):
        """return true if alien is at edge of screen"""
        screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        if self.rect.right >= screen_rect.right or self.rect.left <= 0:
        return True
    def update(self):
        """Move the alien to the right"""
        self.x += (self.settings.alien_speed * self.settings.fleet_direction)
        self.rect.x = self.x
```

ship.py

```
import pygame
    class Ship:
        """A class to manage the ship."""
        def __init__(self, ai_game):
            """Initialize the ship and set its starting position."""
            self.screen = ai_game.screen
            self.settings = ai_game.settings
            self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()

            #load the ship image and get its rect
            self.image = pygame.image.load('Images/ship.bmp')
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            #Start each new ship at the bottom of the screen
            self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom
            #Store a decimal value for the ships horizontal position
            self.x = float(self.rect.x)

            #Movement flag
            self.moving_right = False
            self.moving_left = False
        def update(self):
            """Update the ships position based on the movement flag."""
            #update the ships x value not the rect
            if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
                self.x += self.settings.ship_speed
            if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
                self.x -= self.settings.ship_speed
            #Update rect from self.x
            self.rect.x = self.x

        def blitme(self):
            """Draw the ship at its current location."""
            self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

Comment: Did you check the website to see if they made corrections? Also this shouldn’t be you process for learning to code. You should be picking up the topics as you read and you should be able to debug the code yourself. Copy-pasting all your code and asking for answers won’t help you learn at all. Also I don’t understand how you would expect us to find your error when we don’t know what the error is? At least give us the error message and please the line where it occurred. I see you’re new to SO, but SO is not a site to get your code debugged.

Comment: We don't have any of the assets, are you able to provided a minimum reproducible example that we can attempt to help you debug?

Comment: I added all the classes code. The error occurs at the end line: ai.run_game(). It says group object has no sprite.

Comment: I also checked the website and there are no corrections associated with this project. I have been having this error for a few days and I tried to figure it out on my own but I cannot figure it out so that is the reason I decided to ask about it on here, I figured somebody could figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You have two groups, `bullets` and `aliens`. The error message says that a group doesn't have a `sprite` attribute. So searching for `bullets.sprite` and `aliens.sprite`, I find this:

```
def _change_fleet_direction(self):
    """Drop the entire fleet and change direction"""
    for alien in self.aliens.sprite():
        alien.rect.y += self.settings.fleet_drop_speed
    self.settings.fleet_direction *= -1
```

I believe the error is in the `for` line. You need to loop over `self.aliens.sprites()` with an s, not `self.alien.sprite()`.

Comment: Ok that fixed that error. It works now but when I stop debugging there is still an exception on line ai.run_game() after I stop debugging. The program works it just shows the exception when debugging is stopped.

Comment: As someone else said, SO really isn't a place for a bunch of back and forth debugging a specific project. It's for answering one specific question about how something works, with maybe some concepts thrown in. I'm the author of PCC, and my email is in my profile. If you want to write with a followup question, you are welcome to do so. You can also share your whole project over email easier than you can share it here.